# Rewrite all traffic to https with port

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, plesk

Got a vServer and plesk installed on it (Apache backend, Nginx reverse proxy), plesk is listening on port 8443.
I use the hostname as a domain for easier accesss and SSL certificate domain. So I would like to redirect ALL traffic to specific one:

What I got so far is this rule

```
return 301 https://www.DOMAIN.com:8443/;
```

which leads everything to the Plesk Panel URL but if someone is using this

```
https://DOMAIN.com:8443
```

he won't be redirected to

```
https://www.DOMAIN.com:8443
```

and the SSL certificate won't work (domain based). How can I force every traffic (http and https with the ports 80 and 8443) to

`https://www.DOMAIN.com:8443`

Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot reliably redirect `https://domain.com` to `https://www.domain.com`, because the browser will refuse to make the connection in the first place. Besides that, the syntax `return 301 url` does not look familiar to me. Is this nginx syntax? If so, why was this question tagged `.htaccess`?

Comment: because I am open for a solution based on Nginx or htaccess

anyway, if this is not "possible" I buy a second SSL certificate for the DOMAIN.COM instead .... just want to avoid costs ;)

Comment: Share your entire Nginx configuration please.

Answer (score 1):

You could HTACCESS to do it:

***The Code***

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}:8443 [R=301,L]
```

What this does is check if the user is trying to access the site without using www and if so redirect to www on the specific port that you wanted.

If you already have your port 80 traffic redirecting to port 8443 and you just want to redirect the rule for www, what I have listed above will work. You can also have mod rewrite redirect based on the port used.

It would look like this:

***The Code***

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}:8443 [R=301,L]
```

You would just need to make sure that each virtual host you are using has the mod rewrite rule in place. You might have to create a virtual host for the extra ports you want to use. The only thing these virtual hosts would have is the redirect rule. Otherwise you might get 404 errors.